# How to set textView buttons in Android that change text in an editText

Tags: android

First of all I have made a main layout using xml. This layout contains textView buttons 0,1,2..9, DEL and -

I also have in same layout, an editText field and random question showing to user(textView).

Now, user should use (touch) the textView buttons to enter an answer e.g. change text in editText field.

Can anybody advise simplest solution?

Please note that I **don't** want to create separate keyboard layout for this I just want to use buttons to set text.

I tried doing this by making an `onClickListener` for each button, but app crashes as if the activity is not registered in manifest and I am not really sure how to go about it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **DO**  need to set an `onClickListener` for your buttons.

An example of my implementation of this is as follows:

```
 final Button b0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
    b0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            active.setText(active.getText() + "0");
        }
    });
```

Where `active` is the `editText` field you wish to input to.
This current configuration adds the number `0` to the end of whatever is already present in the text box. Obviously you can modify this easily at will.

Be sure to put the above code in your `onCreate` bundle.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, That did the trick. Is there any way to streamline OnClickListener so I don't create it manually for each button. May using switch case.

Comment: I have not looked into it but will let you know! p.s. if it did the trick, mind accepting the answer so I get the rep for it? ;) haha Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are probably close. You just need to add a section in your manifest file that will tell the system which activities are included with your application.

Post your manifest file. I can try to help you with it.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Manifest file was fine after all. I was setting text from wrong class.